# Lists with Parent Child Relationshiips - add records

Tags: 2010

I am creating a CRM system in SharePoint 2010, and I would like to be able to have the main list have the customers, and then sub lists with contact information, notes information, task information and libraries.  I would like to have a page that shows the profile of the customer with webparts of each of the associated items, and when I add an item, I want it to automatically know who the customer is and associate it to the correct customer.

Comment: So what is your exact problem here, you haven't really asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

PirateEric has actually answered this kind of question, and if I'm not wrong you are looking for the same:

[How can I pass a Parameter via Query String to populate a lookup field on a New Item Form/DVWP?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29613/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-via-query-string-to-populate-a-lookup-field-on-a-new)

So you have to pass the CustomerId in Query String to this page and use JavaScript/JQuery to set the value of the lookup, if you don't want the user to change the value.. you just make it read-only or even hide the lookup control..

Answer (score 0):

You can create webpart page which displaying your list in webpart zone. Then you can link the webpart. here is the sample of parent-child relationship:
http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4